# JavaScript fragments in HTML attributes: special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm using AngularJS 1.4 for my app. I have some attributes in my HTML templates that use logical operators such as:

```
<p ng-if="!edit.model && !model.length">...</p>
```

My text editor marks the `&&` as an error, presumably because it's not HTML-escaped. Should I really change it to `&amp;&amp;`? It's not like I'm using an [ambiguous ampersand](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-ambiguous-ampersand).

Comment: You shouldn't be having any issues using && in an ng-if. Does the ng-if work with single boolean evaluations? Are you sure that Angular is transpiling?

Comment: Sounds like a problem more with your text editor than your code

Comment: In questions like this, its good to mention _which_ editor you are using.

Comment: It's Atom, but really I'm asking if using a bare `&` in an attribute is valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I really change it to `&amp;&amp;`?

**No. Never.**
Or yes, if your priority is your current editor syntax engine instead of functionality of your application.

> My text editor marks the && as an error, presumably because it's not HTML-escaped.

Because it is <s>stupid</s> too over-protective (generalist) with [HTML Codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).

---

And it's a valid question from you, let's see some examples:

This **will work** just fine:

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hello" ng-model="hello">
  <label for="hello">Say only Hello!</label>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="goodbye" ng-model="goodbye">
  <label for="goodbye">Say only Goodbye!</label>
</p>
<h1 ng-show="hello&&!goodbye">Hello!</h1>
<h1 ng-show="!hello&&goodbye">Goodbye!</h1>
```

<sup>See at https://plnkr.co/edit/93LAQJJ1bwTNPteLCv5Q?p=preview.</sup>

But, this **won't**:

```
[..]
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="not" ng-model="not">
  <label for="not">Say only Not!</label>
</p>
<h1 ng-show="hello&&!not">Hello!</h1>
<h1 ng-show="!hello&&not">Not!</h1>
```

<sup>See at https://plnkr.co/edit/HRVigpQCCg1hQCW25Xgk?p=preview.</sup>

But, this **will**:

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="not" ng-model="not">
  <label for="not">Say only Not!</label>
</p>
<h1 ng-show="hello && !not">Hello!</h1>
<h1 ng-show="!hello && not">Not!</h1>
```

<sup>See at https://plnkr.co/edit/u3uNt9xHMnvtI0HZynlJ?p=preview.</sup>

It will be fine **as long as you do not put a value that contains an HTML Code**.

Comment: Thanks, I take it then that it's valid HTML to have a bare `&`. I've submitted [a bug report](https://github.com/atom/language-html/issues/116) against the editor.